# SCSS: Add element to existing rule

Tags: html, css, sass

I have some rules nested inside each other, and I'd like to add another unrelated element to one of the rules.
For example if I have

```
#element1{
   display: block;

   .sub-element1 {
      background: yellow;

      .sub-element2 {
      color: red;
      }
   }
}
```

and then I'd like to add another element (#element2) to use same rules as .sub-element2, so compiled code would look like this:

```
#element1{
   display:block
}
#element1 .sub-element1 {
   background:yellow
}
#element1. sub-element1 .sub-element2, #element2 {
   color: red;
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Nope there is no possible to directly extend the properties of `#element1` `.sub-element2` child you can extend `@extend #element1`into element2. moreover your question is not clear..

Answer (score 2):

You could use a mixin. You can add rules to a mixin, then include the mixins where you want them:

```
@mixin redcolor {
    color:red;
}
```

Then simply include this mixin in any selector:

```
.subelement2, #element2 {
    @include redcolor;
}
```

More on mixins here:
http://sass-lang.com/guide

Answer (score 0):

Use `@extend`.

```
#element2 {
  @extend .sub-element2
}
```

The output created by this will however also copy the selector chain, so this would be the output:

```
#element1. sub-element1 .sub-element2, #element2 {
  color: red;
}
```

Perhaps that is what you want, but I can imagine it's not.

In this case you'll need to write an `@extend only` selector. It works much like an `@include`, **except it generates the compact output you outline in your question.** You could do it many ways, this is one of them:

```
%red {
  color: red;
}

#element1{
   display: block;

   .sub-element1 {
      background: yellow;

      .sub-element2 {
        @extend %red;
      }
   }
}

#element2 {
  @extend %red;
}
```

[Here's a link to it in the official docs](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend).